# Is there some way to analyze nominal data with repeated measures when there is a very small sample size?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, repeated-measures, small-sample, bioinformatics

So I have some data of 16 patients who were subjected to a test a different number of times (some only once, some as many as 7 times). The response variable is definitely nominal (I wasn't involved in the experimental design or in conducting the tests at all), and this is high dimensional data because there are at least five dependent variables of interest (they actually measured about 20 but only care about a few) and about 10 independent variables.

I know this isn't reallyconductive to a robust statistical approach, but is there something that could be done to find whether any of the independent variables are correlated to any of the dependent variables?

I have considered multinomial regression and the CochranQ test, but I don't think those are valid under these circumstances.

I could try going for a descriptive analysis but this data is supposed to be used for publication.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you should stick with descriptive analysis; this can sometimes get published. 

But this does remind me of the great line from Fisher:

"To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a post mortem examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of."

Comment: I absolutely can tell what this experiment died from smh